# Adding class to "external link" only for images- page content in TYPO3

Tags: hyperlink, typo3, typoscript

In TYPO3 page content for images, we have the option to link to external links and it also gives the option to add class in the `link-popup CSS-Class`  field.

Is there a way to add the `**class for external links only**` through TS?

```
tt_content.image.20.1.imageLinkWrap {
    linkParams.ATagParams {
        dataWrap = class="external"
    }
    }
}
```

The above TS code adds class to all the links, is there a way to add only to external links?

Comment: just in case, this is something that can be done via jQuery easily (putting this as a comment so I can't get downvotes :-)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to do this via CSS 3 selectors.

E.g. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attr_begin.asp